# How to use bracket notation to access model property inside the loop in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Here what I trying to achieve :

```
var userList = _db.users.ToList();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in userList)
{
    sb.AppendLine($"{item["ActivityName"]}"); //Want to access property like that.
    sb.AppendLine($"{item.ActivityName}"); //Working fine
}
```

Comment: Unless your model is a dictionary (specifically `Dicitionary<string, object>`) you can't do this. But you can use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection).

Comment: Oh yes, i can achieve using reflection. Thank you.

Comment: Also you can implemet indexer in the model itself and cache the reflection there.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @GuruStron